# Select starting with class in jquery like in CSS

Tags: jquery, css

We could select as the followings in css

```
li[class^=navs]{/*css code here*}
```

but how could I select like the above in jquery

I tried but seems wrong:

```
$('li[class^=navs]').css(/*css code here*/);
```

---

Tried with quotes:

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Zx3xE/)

---

**Update**

html

```
<div id="banner"></div>
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#banner').prepend('<ul id="navs"></ul>');
for (var i = 1; i < 8; i++){
$('#navs').append('<li class="navs'+i+'"></li>');
}
$('li[class^="navs"]').css('width':'20px','height':'20px','background-color':'red');
});
```

[updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Zx3xE/2/)

Comment: where is the html element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you need the quotes around the value:

```
$('li[class^="navs"]').css(/*css code here*/);
```

From your fiddle, the line where you set the CSS takes an object:

```
$('li[class^="navs"]').css('width':'20px','height':'20px','background-color':'red');
```

should be:

```
$('li[class^="navs"]').css({'width':'20px','height':'20px','background-color':'red'});
```

The [syntax](http://api.jquery.com/css/) you were using is only valid when setting only one property (`.css(propertyName, value)`).

Comment: @C-Link Can you post your HTML then?

Comment: using quotes is not necessary.

Comment: @undefined Correct, but if the class has some special characters in it (such as a -), then they are.  I wasn't sure if this was the actual class OP was using or not.

Comment: @C-Link, [I think you may have a different issue](http://jsfiddle.net/9VEdf/).

Comment: @C-Link Updated.  You had a syntax error in your .css() call.

Answer (score 2):

You did not use a proper object literal, you need to wrap your css properties in `{}`.

```
$('li[class^="navs"]').css('width':'20px','height':'20px','background-color':'red');
```

Should be:

```
$('li[class^="navs"]').css({'width':'20px','height':'20px','background-color':'red'});
                           ^                                                       ^
```

This would be much more readily apparent if you'd chosen to format your code in a reasonable fashion.

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Krdhc/)

---

<sub>This addresses issues in the original version of the question.</sub>

Both formats should include quotes around the value, browsers may be supporting a similar syntax for greater compatibility, but jQuery doesn't:

```
$('li[class^="navs"]')
```

Another important note is that you shouldn't be relying on the order of classes that are present on a DOM node. `class="foo bar"` is equivalent to `class="bar foo"`.

Comment: @C-Link, you *are* running the jQuery *after* the nodes have been added to the DOM *aren't* you?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('li[class^="nav"]').css({color: 'pink'});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kJ7Gx/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a object as the argument to [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-properties)

```
$('li[class^="navs"]').css({
    'width': '20px',
    'height': '20px',
    'background-color': 'red'
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/C6DD7/)

Answer (score 1):

[.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-properties) documentation

for multiple css you have to use `.css({})`

```
$('li[class^="navs"]').css({'width': '20px', 'height': '20px', 'background-color': 'red'});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/C6DD7/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
$('li[class^="navs"]').css('width':'20px','height':'20px','background-color':'red');
```

It should be

```
$('li[class^="navs"]').css({
    'width':'20px',
    'height':'20px',
    'background-color':'red'
});
```

Notice the `{}`, you should pass an object, instead of string, when you have multiple `css` values and you missed the `{}` but used `:`.
[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/LGrQB/1/)